# Serialized Hash Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, activerecord, serialization, hash

I've just started Rails dev and have a question about inputing data into a serialized hash in my database from a url with a variable number of params. I'm trying to figure out how to implement a url with any number of param/values in the form (`action?1=.5&2=.6&3=.1` etc) that I want to add to my serialized hash.  If my hash already has some key/values previously stored, how do I add more to the same hash? I want all the data to be in one column.

I have a method where I pass it a model object:

```rb
def add_data_to_hash(obj)
  params.each do |key, value|
    if (key.to_i.is_a?(Integer) && key.to_i != 0) then
      obj.hash[key] = value
      obj.save
    end
  end
end
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this maybe?

this should go on the controller

```
new_values = {}
url = request.fullpath.split("?").last
url.split("&").each do |kv|
  pair = kv.split("=")
  new_values[pair[0].to_i] = pair[1]
end
new_value.delete 0
```

and something like this inside your method

```
new_values.each do |k,v|
  object.hash[k] = v
end
object.save
```

Also it is better to call object.save once you finished updating the hash and not for every Integer key :)

Comment: While this is well intentioned, you're completely ignoring how to properly parse URL parameters. Both parts need to be de-`%` encoded. Both `Rack:Utils.parse_nested_query` and `CGI::parse` will do this properly without you having to re-invent the wheel.

Comment: `Rack::Utils` will handle Rails-style nested parameters, so things like `{ 'a' => { 'b' => 'c' } }` will be properly encoded and decoded.